# Left recursion elimination

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, computation-theory

I have this grammar

```
S->S+S|SS|(S)|S*|a
```

I want to know how to eliminate the left recursion from this grammar because the `S+S` is really confusing...

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if we can simplify the given grammar.

```
S -> S*|S+S|SS|(S)|a
```

We can write it as;

```
S -> S*|SQ|SS|B|a
Q -> +S
B -> (S)
```

Now, you can eliminate left recursion in familiar territory.

```
S  ->  BS'|aS'
S' ->  *S'|QS'|SS'|e
Q  ->  +S
B  ->  (S)
```

Note that e is epsilon/lambda.

We have removed the left recursion, so we no longer have need of Q and B.

```
S  ->  (S)S'|aS'
S' ->  *S'|+SS'|SS'|e
```

[You'll find this useful when dealing with left recursion elimination](http://www.d.umn.edu/~hudson/5641/l11m.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

<del>My answer using theory from [this reference](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cs415/reading/RemovingLeftRecursion.pdf)</del>

### How to Eliminate Left recursion in Context-Free-Grammar.

```
S -->  S+S | SS | S*    |        a | (S)
      --------------            -------   
      Sα form                   β form    
      Left-Recursive-Rules      Non-Left-Recursive-Rules
```

We can write like

> S ---> Sα<sub>1</sub> | Sα<sub>2</sub> | Sα<sub>3</sub>    |              β<sub>1</sub> | β<sub>2</sub>

Rules to convert in equivalent Non-recursive grammar:

> S --->  β<sub>1</sub> | β<sub>2</sub>
>     Z --->  α<sub>1</sub> |
>   α<sub>2</sub> | α<sub>3</sub>
>      Z --->  α<sub>1</sub>Z |
>   α<sub>2</sub>Z | α<sub>3</sub>Z
>      S --->  β<sub>1</sub>Z | β<sub>2</sub>Z

Where

> α<sub>1</sub> = +S
>    α<sub>2</sub> = S
>    α<sub>3</sub> = *

**And** `β`-productions not start starts with `S`:

> β<sub>1</sub> = a
>    β<sub>2</sub> = (S)

**Grammar without left-recursion:**

Non- left recursive Productions S --> β<sub>n</sub>

```
S -->  a | (S)
```

Introduce new variable `Z` with following productions: Z ---> α<sub>n</sub>  and Z --> α<sub>n</sub>Z

```
Z --> +S | S | * 

and 

Z --> +SZ | SZ | *Z
```

And new `S` productions:  S --> β<sub>n</sub>Z

```
S -->  aZ | (S)Z
```

---

Second form (answer)

Productions `Z --> +S | S | *` and  `Z --> +SZ | SZ | *Z` can be combine as  `Z --> +SZ | SZ | *Z| ^`  where `^` is null-symbol.

`Z --> ^` use to remove `Z`   from production rules.

So **second answer**:

`S -->  aZ | (S)Z`  **and** `Z --> +SZ | SZ | *Z| ^`